# Problem about the concatenation of two dataframes

Tags: python, dataframe

I want to concatenate two dataframes by using the following expression

```
new_data = pd.concat([first_data, second_data], axis=1)
```

first_data:

```
id      Col1      Col2     Col3
1       aaaa      bbbb     cccc      
2       dddd      eeee     ffff
3       gggg      hhhh     iiii
```

Second Data:

```
Col4    Col5
mmmm    nnnn
oooo    pppp
qqqq    rrrr
```

I get this problem:

```
id      Col1      Col2     Col3      Col4    Col5
1       nan       nan      nan       mmmm    nnnn
2       nan       nan      nan       oooo    pppp
3       nan       nan      nan       qqqq    rrrr
4       aaaa      bbbb     cccc      nan     nan
5       dddd      eeee     ffff      nan     nan
6       gggg      hhhh     iiii      nan     nan
```

Comment: Can't reproduce. Please provide [mcve]

Comment: try to use ignore_index=True on pd.concat(...)

Comment: I reproduced what you posted and it worked fine for me. You probably have some index issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your answers, I do appreciate your help, My problem was concerning the Index of the first table, It was like 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 6 ... I create a new Index By the following syntax and it works perfectly

```
first_data= first_data.reset_index()
first_data= first_data.drop('index', 1)
```

Comment: you could also use: pd.concat([first_data, second_data.reindex_like(first_data)], axis=1). reindex_like to set indexes of second_data the same as the indexes of first_data

Answer (score -1):

I'm not an active pandas user but you can as well use `pd.merge` like.

```
pd.merge(first_data, second_data, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```